# SAPUI5 custom pseudo-event

Tags: sapui5

What are the best practices for defining a custom pseudo-event in SAPUI5/OpenUI5?

For example, let's say I wanted to fire an event on an extended sap.m.Button when pressed and held for several seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are yet any 'best practices', I really think there's only 'one' practice ;-) But I'm eager to learn any other takes, so if anyone can comment on this, please do not hesitate!

I think the general idea is just to define your event; the UI5 framework then automatically generates methods for registering (`attach<YourEvent>`), deregistering (`detach<YourEvent>`), and firing events (`fire<YourEvent>`).

For example:

```js
return ControlToExtend.extend("your.custom.Control", {
  metadata: {
    properties: {
      // etc...
    },
    aggregations: {
      "_myButton": {
        type: "sap.m.Button",
        multiple : false,
        visibility: "hidden"
      },
      // etc...
    },
    associations: {
      // etc...
    },
    events: {
      yourCustomEvent: {
        allowPreventDefault: true,
        parameters: {
          "passAlong": { type: "string" }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  init: function() {
    ControlToExntend.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    var oControl = this, oMyButton;
    oMyButton = new Button({ // Button required from "sap/m/Button"
      // ...,
      press: function (oEvent) {
        oControl.fireYourCustomEvent({
          passAlong: "Some dummy data to pass along"
        });
      }
    });
    this.setAggregation("_myButton", oMyButton);
  },

  // etc...
});
```

Hope this explains a bit.

Answer (score 2):

For custom events, you can [wrap jquery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

So, use a general pattern like this can be followed:

```
events: {
    someEvent: {}
}

onBeforeRendering
    var domNode = this.getDomRef();
    $(domNode).unbind('someEvent')

onAfterRendering
    var self = this, domNode = this.getDomRef();
    $(domNode).bind('someEvent', function() {
        self.fireSomeEvent({
            customProp: customValue
        })
    });
```

A client of the control can do things like:

```
new CustomControl({
    someEvent: function( o ) {
        alert('customProp: ' + o.getParameter('customProp'));
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation / best practice is to register the event using such as jQuery.bind (*and remove using jQuery.unbind() to avoid memory leak*).

Find additional information (copied from Tim's comment): https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/91f1b3856f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html

........

Good Luck

Comment: For browser events and control events, this will work. However, the original question was regarding Pseudo events, and -- from the link you supplied -- it is mentioned: *Pseudo events are semantically enriched and can be handled by just implementing an on<eventName> method. They **cannot** be used with jQuery.bind()*

Comment: You are right. I missed that psuedo part. When we say psuedo, are we referring to those events which were coming from browser but not implemented by jQuery (or the frameworks)? Is that right? When it said these events are semantically enriched, who is enriching?